# Joining sys.columns and sys.tables on database name

Tags: sql-server, database, join

I'm writing a application using a database backend, but I need to find out all the column names and the table they belong to via SQL. I know you can query `sys.columns`, `sys.tables`, and `sys.databases`, but what I want to do is join them all to get something like the below result (basically displaying all columns and tables from the DB):

```
    +-----------+------------+
    | Tablename | columnname |
    +-----------+------------+
    | Table1    | Id         |
    | Table1    | Name       |
    | Table1    | Owner      |
    | Table2    | Id         |
    | Table2    | Name       |
    | Table2    | True       |
    +-----------+------------+
```

I've had a good look in the sys schema, but I can't find any parent reference in `sys.columns` or `sys.tables`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You generally do not want to query the sys.columns or sys.tables (or any system tables) directly. You should be using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views. These views are the ANSI standard way of querying system tables that could change from release to release. The INFORMATION_SCHEMA views will not change, at least in a breaking way.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,* 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = <TableName> AND TABLE_SCHEMA= <SchemaName>
```

Of course, the WHERE clause is optional here and could be omitted to see all columns in all tables etc.

Comment: well, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is slow when you have lots of tables (query like this take about 30s on my database where i have ~1800 tables - more then half of them created by bug, thats why we noticed it - query to sys.columns is almost instant). Yes, i know, this is not realy the "generally" situation, just FYI :)

Answer (score 37):

[Randy Minder's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37880011/1501497) answer is the most correct one. But in case if you want to continue with sys.columns and sys.tables join them on object_id.

```sql
select   tab.name, col.name
from    sys.columns col
inner join sys.tables tab
    on col.object_id = tab.object_id
```

You can use this to get the table names from sys.columns table it self.

```sql
select object_name(object_id),name 
from sys.columns
```

Answer (score 0):

Also: I was writing dymamic sql to insert back into table and you can't insert into calculated columns and the INFORMATION_SCHEMA doesn't seem to have that, where as you can use sys.columns to exclude columns in the INSERT statement that are calculated.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).